# PHP-FPM/ZF3 download php file when hit root domain

Tags: php, nginx, php-7, zf3

This baffled me big time. When I visit the domain, it download the `index.php` file. When I visit domain/index.php, it's working fine. I have tried to comment here and there, just can't fix it. This one is `Zend Framework 3`. I have other php site on the same server. They are fine. I start to wonder it's ZF3 special now.

My nginx is like this:

```
server {
  listen       80;
  server_name  xxx.xxx.com;
  index index.php index.html;
  root         /data/www/xxx/public;

  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include       fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME /data/www/xxx/public/index.php; 
  }

  access_log logs/worth.jusfeel.cn.log main;
}
```

I have tried other settings as well. It's the same. The url in the addressbar change to `..domain/index.php` , but still download the `index.php` file.

```
server {
  listen      80;
  server_name www.example.com;
  root        /var/www/www.example.com/myapplication;
  index       index.html index.htm index.php;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Downloading the `index.php` file means that nginx doesn't using php-fpm to process file. Most common reason behind this situation is misconfiguration between nginx and php-fpm.

Checklist:

1. Make sure that you didn't disabled the [cgi.fix_pathinfo](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.cgi.fix-pathinfo) directive in `php.ini`. It provides real `PATH_INFO`/`PATH_TRANSLATED` support for CGI and it is enabled `(1)` by default.
2. Make sure that root of your virtual host points to `public` directory of your ZF3 application. In this case you may need to replace it from `/var/www/www.example.com/myapplication` to `/var/www/www.example.com/myapplication/public`
3. Most important part is you need a proper [fastcgi_split_path_info](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_split_path_info) directive in `location ~ \.php$ { }` block since all PHP requests processed through `index.php`. This directive defines a regular expression that captures a value for the nginx `$fastcgi_path_info` variable.

For example:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
  fastcgi_pass            127.0.0.1:9000;
  fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+.php)(/.+)$;
  fastcgi_param           SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  include                 fastcgi_params;
}
```

Hope it helps.